# Azure DevOps pipelines: REST API call to update scaling parameters of an agent pool

Tags: azure, devops, scale, pool, agent

How could I use a REST API call to update parameters, like:

1. Maximum number of virtual machines in the scale set
2. Number of agents to keep on standby
3. Delay in minutes before deleting excess idle agents
   (I.e., the ones you set in the Settings tab of the Agent Pool settings).

Note, that the underlying VMSS is set to "manual scaling", so autoscaling is not done for the VMSS (which would be easy using an az vmss ... CLI call).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below REST API to Update settings on a specified Elastic Pool.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/elasticpools/{poolId}?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

You can do all the updates as mentioned in this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/elasticpools/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) like `maxCapacity`,`timeToLiveMinutes` and others.

You can do a REST call to update setting `desiredIdle` to keep the Number of machines to have ready waiting for jobs.